# Webapp deployed design looks strange

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, tomcat7

So im developing small webapp in Eclipse. **When i run it on local server in Eclipse**, it runs perfectly and looks ok. Check this picture

[image: This is when i run app localy]

**but when i deploy application** ( copy from local server webapps/appname to server/webapps ) on server ( VPS hosted at digitalocen ), it looks like this:
[image: This is when app is runned on server]

can anyone tell me some idea or something what can cause this problem / design change ?
Looks like primefaces library is ripped off or something i dont know.

Thanks !

EDIT:
As L-Ray sayd i checked it via FireBug and i got this,

[image]

so i just need to find out whats the problem, permissions or what ?

Comment: Is this application deployed to intranet (i.e inside your company N/W) or internet(Usually production)? And on which browser you have seen this behavior?

Comment: On internet, i deployed it on VPS and i can acces it via ip/appName since i dont have domain yet and it just for testing. This happens in Firefox. But when i runn it localy it looks fine... Same happens in chrome

Comment: Open a Browser with Developer Tools (e.g. Firefox with installed Firebug), activate the Network-Check, load the page and check if any files are not loaded correctly (404/403-errors). Also, cleaning your browser Cache completely might help, if you earlier loaded former versions of css, js, etc.

Comment: It looks like one of your css is unreachable and thus it's not deployed most probably.

Comment: would you post the complet xhtml page (login) including the template if you use template. (important is the HEADER incl. Meta Data)

Comment: If server is beyond your control, I'd report it to the serveradmin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSWER:
Problem was that my project/application name in eclipse was like:
appName Maven Webapp <- it contains spaces and then some resources can not be found

i just renamed project name to: appName without any space and it works.

Thank you all guys !!!